# password verifier java: linking booleans?

Tags: java

I just started with java a few weeks ago, and am trying to make a program to verify that a password is at least 10 characters, has at least one each of:upper case, lower case, number, and is only alphanumeric characters.

Below is the code I have so far. It's more English than code actually, but what I'm trying to do is run several loops under one boolean (at least that's what I think I'm doing). Can you help me understand how exactly booleans work, and if it's possible for several conditions to be tested under one boolean, as I'm trying to do below?

Thanks!

```
public class validatingPassword
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
String password= isSecurePassword("testcase");
System.out.println(isSecurePassword);
}

public static boolean isSecurePassword(String password)
{   
password.charAt(x);
int lengthPassword= password.length(); 
if (lengthPassword < 10);
return false; 

for (int x = 0; x < lengthPassword; x++)
        {
    if ('A' <=x && x <= 'Z');}
    else if 
    return false;

    for (int x = 0; x< lengthPassword; x++) 
            {
        ('a' <=x && x <= 'z'); }
        else if 
        return false:

        for (int x = 0; x < lengthPassword; x++) 
                {
            ('0' <=x && x <= '9');}
            return true;  
                }
    else if
    {
    x++;
    return false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code above can't even get compiled, pls correct all the errors before clarify your problems:)

Comment: I know it can't compile...I just had no idea how to format things (ie. what is and isn't allowed), and I find the biggest problem is figuring out java syntax. Brackets give me headaches. Need to start going to all the prof's office hours I guess :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just give the correct code undocumented. Because I think you've got the right ideas, but are missing a bit of Java syntax. You might debug the code with single-step through all commands.

```
public class ValidatingPassword {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] passwords = { "testcase", "T3stCas3%45" };
        for (String password : passwords) {
            System.out.println(password + " : " + isSecurePassword(password));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Is this a secure password?
     * At least 10 characters, at least one capital letter, one small
     * letter and one digit.
     * 
     * @param password never null.
     * @return whether password is secure.
     */
    public static boolean isSecurePassword(String password) {

        int lengthPassword = password.length();
        if (lengthPassword < 10) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean hasCapital = false;
        boolean hasSmallLetter = false;
        boolean hasDigit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthPassword; i++) {
            char ch = password.charAt(i);
            if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {
                hasCapital = true;
            }
            if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {
                hasSmallLetter = true;
            }
            if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {
                hasDigit = true;
            }
        }
        return hasCapital && hasSmallLetter && hasDigit;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!! I know my java syntax is horrible so it's good to read properly written code and decipher how to phrase stuff

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to nest the boolean statements... your bracers are all messed up though.

You have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < lengthPassword; x++){
if ('A' <=x && x <= 'Z');}
else if {
return false;
```

which should look more like:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < lengthPassword; x++)
    {
        if ('A' <=x && x <= 'Z') {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If you use else if it will expect a conditional statement, so you want to just use else which needs to be in the for statement along with the if.

You also do not need to increment the x as this is done by the for loop.

You can also combine them all in the one for statement rather than having each its own:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < lengthPassword; x++)
    {
        if ('A' <=x && x <= 'Z') {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        if ('a' <=x && x <= 'z') {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }       
        if ('0' <=x && x <= '9') {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am not even sure if what you are trying to do will work. If I was trying to do this I would do it with regular expressions.

Use indenting it really helps.

Comment: thanks, but I'm still confused. when you commented //Do nothing, are you saying that the code will do nothing and go on to the next loop checking for lower case, then numbers etc, or are you saying that my "if" statement itself is not doing anything?

Comment: They are just comments meaning that if the conditions of the if statement are true it will just skip down to the next if statement and check that one. It would be better to check for the negative conditions in the if statement and return from there saving the need for the else but for a sake of brevity I just reused what you had.